# Write over Firebase DB value only if the current value is greater than the stored value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do you check to see if a value is greater than a Firebase value and only write over it if the new value is higher?

This is my current code when scores are submitted but it just replaces the score value with the new one whether or not it is greater and adds to the total score either way as well.  I need to only update the score if it's higher and only add to the total score if it's higher.

```
let dbRef2 = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    dbRef2.queryOrdered(byChild: "Live Scoring Male/\(String(describing: CompLabel.text!))/score\(String(describing: ProblemLabel.text!))").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        var previousScore = snapshot.value as? Double
        print (previousScore)

    })

    if Double(ScoreLabel.text!)! > previousScore {

    self.dbRef.child("Live Scoring Male/\(String(describing: CompLabel.text!))/score\(String(describing: ProblemLabel.text!))").setValue(Int(ScoreLabel.text!))


    self.dbRef.child("Live Scoring Male/\(String(describing: CompLabel.text!))/attempts\(String(describing: ProblemLabel.text!))").setValue(Int(AttemptsLabel.text!))

    let dbRef1 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Live Scoring Male/\(String(describing: CompLabel.text!))/scoreTotal")

    dbRef1.queryOrdered(byChild: "scoreTotal").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let currentScore = snapshot.value as? Double

        let newScore = ["scoreTotal": Double(currentScore!) + Double(self.ScoreLabel.text!)! - Double(self.AttemptsLabel.text!)!*0.1]

        self.dbRef.child("Live Scoring Male/\(String(describing: self.CompLabel.text!))").updateChildValues(newScore)

        })

        dbRef1.removeAllObservers()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you'll need to query your database for the current score and then check client side if the new value is greater than the current value. I'm not sure what kind of app you have but if your app allows multiple users to post their new scores simultaneously then should do this using a transaction block just incase two people do it at the exact same time

Here is an example of how to use a transaction block for your situation...

```
    func updateScore(newScore: Int){
    let ref = fireRootRef.child("currentScore")

    ref.runTransactionBlock({ (data)-> FIRTransactionResult in
        print("ENETERED TRANSACTION BLOCK and data is \(data)")

        //here `value` is equal to the current value stored in firebase
        var value = data.value as? Int
        if value == nil {
            value = newScore
        } else if value! < newScore {
            value = newScore
        }


        return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: data)
    },
                                    andCompletionBlock: {(error, bool, snapshot)-> Void in
                                        if error != nil{
                                            print("ERROR in transaction block \(error)")
                                        }
                                        print("bool value in completion block = \(bool)")
                                        print("transaction block snapshot = \(snapshot)")
    })
}
```

If only one user can alter this value then you can simply query the database like

```
func updateScore(newScore: Int) {
    let ref = fireRootRef.child("currentScore")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot)-> Void in
        if let currentScore = snapshot.value as? Int, newScore > currentScore {
           ref.setValue(newScore)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: can't we put data validation in firebase rather doing it in code?

Comment: hm not sure. Do you mean via Firebase Rules?